# How to run SDKMAN on shell script

Tags: shell, sh, sdkman

I am trying to run sdkman on a shell script that I call `run.sh`. This is what the inside of the shell script looks like:

```
sdk use java 8.0.302-open
```

When I run the command in a terminal, it works. But when I run it in a shell script, I get this error:

```
run.sh: 1: sdk: not found
```

**Anyone knows how to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it for me; Although this may not work for others.

I placed `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the shell script, and then added this after it:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Then my shell script was able to be ran using:

```
./run.sh
```

sdkman was able to work this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MAC and fixed it adding this line below `#!/bin/bash`:

> . /Users/myuser/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh